# Container Based Application Clustering System

Tags: apache, web-applications, docker, system-administration

I have a web application set (4 different applications currently) that all have separate host names they are routed to. All of them run on one VM with Apache virtualhost's configured for each. Here is what I would like to do:

Run each application in a container (Docker most preferred and experienced with) and have the host names routed to one IP as it is now but allow a fifth "Handler" route all traffic through it and be able to route traffic to subsequent apps and possibly even load balance the application set.

I have been reading for awhile on how I could possibly do this but from a best practices stand point how would one implement such an objective?

Comment: Not sure about "best practices", but `nginx` would seem to be popular as a load balancer/request router in docker systems.

Comment: I've always been in apache nginx has always been a side project. so I could use nginx just as a request handler / load balancer? but what I've read (admittedly not much) I don't understand it fully. Do you have any documentation? I will do additional research! thank you so much